# SOA UMS Email Populating black list

Tags: email, messaging, soa

I'm sending email notifications through SOA using UMS. However, email server has a limit on the amount of emails sent and some go to invalid emails.

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve notifications of message delivery failure in order to populate a black list. SOA human workflow notifications are sucessfully sent despite the email address, they only record status on gateway delivery. Email client is not registering sent notifications nor is it receiving delivery failure notifications. (Unless I send an email through the email client, not from SOA)

Basically, I would like to know if UMS stores information of delivery failure to recipient (not gateway) and if so how can I access it. In alternative, how can I setup email client to register sent notifications and receive failure reports that can somehow be passed to SOA so they can be analyzed and the email added to a black list.

Any info missing that can help solving this issue just ask and I'll append it to the post.

Best regards,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

You can create an inbound UMS adapter polling the inbox to read all the incoming mails. UMS adapter has a filtering option to read only mails that matches the pattern. Set the pattern to read only delivery failure notifications. That way the polling service will get triggered only for messages with delivery failure.

Try this out and let me know if this solve your problem.

Regards,
Viv